# MVC HttpPost ActionResult issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As described in title my problem is about MVC and ActionResult.

**What we want to achieve:**

Its a recipe website , where you can submit a recipe and search for recipes.

On the submit form we want that if an item is clicked from the dropdownListFor(list of ingredients) that is linked with a IngredientModel, the selected item should be inserted into a listbox (selected ingredients).

**What we have:**

A Controller and HttpPost ActionResult method that is called Submit.

The whole form submit recipe is divided into 3 forms (1 HtmlBeginForm & 2 Html.Partial)

1st form is the add new ingredient (to add new ingredient)txtBox and button.(partial view)
2nd form is addToListBox (where the selected items from dropdownListfor should come into listbox)(partial view)

3rd form is the rest (title, description, steps ,img etc ... and the recipe Submit button.(main view)

**Code:**

http://pastebin.com/UkQ1RDT5

In the RecipeController there is a httpPost ActionResult Submit (which serves to put entire recipe into DataBase) that works , but before we want to put recipe in DB we want to have :

- An httpPost ActionResult AddIngredientToListBox to put the selectedItems from the dropdownListFor in a List  and each time a item is clicked from the dropdownlistfor show that "updated" list  in the listbox with the selected items.

-An  httpPost ActionResult AddNewIngredient that adds an new ingredient into DB (or listbox and afterwards in DB)

**Problem is**:

When the selected item changes from the dropdownList, we're going into the Submit ActionResult and not in the AddIngredientToListBox ActionResult ...

I have searched an entire afternoon with my teacher (im student) and he didn't find the reason neither...

Thank you for your time !

Kind regards.

Comment: Unclear from the linked code (or I missed it) but assuming I read things right you seem to be _nesting forms_ (?). From a high level, you could handle the "building of data" client side with or without an XHR call (UI only or with some server side data respectively) and thereafter "submit" (the "completed" data).

Answer (score 2):

The `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {` statement should specify the name of the controller + action where the form should be posted to. Say, `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddIngredientToListBox", "NameOfYourController")) {`.

Also mind the nesting of the forms. Please check your HTML output, since your razor will render a `<form>` inside another `<form>`